# Jquery validation, alert just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

If I run below, and both fields alder and gender is invalid, it'll alert two times. Is it possible to make it alert just once?

```
$(function(){
            $("#formTest").validate({           
                rules : {
                    alder : {
                        required: true
                    },
                    gender : {
                        required: true
                    }
                }, 

                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    alert("Alert once");
                }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`errorPlacement` is called once for every error - it's not meant to alert a message, but to place it in the form. You can either try to use the **groups** feature, to group you fields together and get a single call for the entire group, or use the [showErrors](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#showerrors) function to capture all errors and present them however you like:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    alert(`Your form contains ${this.numberOfInvalids()} errors`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with this one, since I can use it multiple times. Also thank you for a clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Never used jQuery validate before but this might work:

```
$(function(){
  var checked = false;
  $("#formTest").validate({           
    rules : {
      alder : {
        required: true
      },
      gender : {
        required: true
      }
    }, 

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (!checked) {
        alert("Alert once");
        checked = true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```